# Where is the memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

my dear friends. Could you help me to figure out where do I have memory leak in my application.

There are two activities.

In first activity I'v got a rather big static ArrayList consists of bitmaps and another needed information. I made it static, because I need to take it from another activity, and It's loading takes to much time.

In another activity, I also have one static field, using as a key for getting data which present in an Intent from previous activity.

If I try to start one activity from another and go back several times, I get shutting down VM.

To be more clear, here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class MoviesGallery extends Activity
{
...
private static ArrayList<Movie> films = new ArrayList<Movie>();
...
public void contextButtonsClickHandler(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.play_button:
            Log.d("Context Button", "Play button has clicked");
            mContextButtonHasPressed = true;
            Intent filmData = new Intent(MoviesGallery.this, MovieInfo.class);
            filmData.putExtra(MovieInfo.mPOS,mPOSITION_OF_CLICKED_ITEM);
            startActivityForResult(filmData, 1);
            break;
...
}
```

And this is another activity:

```
public class FilmInfo extends Activity
{
    public static String mPOS = "pos";
    private int mNumOfFilm = -1;
    private LinearLayout mWall;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    mNumOfFilm=extra.getInt(mPOS);
...      
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(MoviesGallery.getMoviesArray().get(mNumOfFilm).getWall()));
    mWall = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Wall);
    mWall.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    ...
        setResult(0);
    }
```

Comment: Please, show us the following methods from both activities: onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that potentially memory-leak point is in `FilmInfo` class member:

```
private LinearLayout mWall;
```

Layout has reference to Activity, which each time changes.
So to avoid keeping reference to dead Activity just use in `FilmInfo` class

```
@Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
     //blah-blah
     mWall=null;
}
```

Anyway recipe is simple - try to avoid keeping objects which might contain references to Activity/Context objects.

Comment: I thought that GC should take mWall after onCreate() runtime, because I haven't any references to mWall

Comment: You're right. You'd better to place mWall=null not in onDestroy(), but in place where you're about to leave FilmInfo activity (usually somewhere in onClick()). Reason is simple, when you're leaving Activity it doesn't actually mean that Activity will be destroyed. It can easily happen that Activity will be reused again. And if Activity will be reused it will have useless reference to mWall

Comment: As I know, finish() function call onDestroy(), I tried to write this function in the code in override onBackPressed() method and LogCat said to me: "Duplicate finish request"

Comment: That`s it!!! I found the leak. I didn`t destroy previous activity, so when I go to another one I create one more Intent object, and put data to it, so I inflate the first Activity until I get VM shut down. Barmaley, Thanks a lot for respond!!!)))

Comment: @teoretic - so where's my "+" :)

Comment: My reputation score doesn't aford me to give you one more vote, please don't be offended